# Making 6 digit pins on array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to ask 6 digit pins from user, I tried this code, it does work. The problem is that it cannot read pin starting from 0. The objective of the code is to read 6 digit pin no matter what the start is, as long as it is an integer it will read the correct output.

````
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int pin[0];

    cin>>pin[0];

    if (pin[0] >= 100000 && pin[0] <= 999999) {
        cout << pin[0];
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid input!";
    }


}```
````

Comment: you can not have a size ZERO array, either set a const size to or use new , malloc to allocate a array for pin. or you meant to say 
    int pin[1];

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand you want to read an integer (you are comparing it to `100000` and `999999`) on the other hand you want to read individual digits into an array. It cannot be both. And you cannot have an array of size `0`.

Just stay with the single integer. If you want to access individual digits you can convert it to a string and access characters (you already made sure that it has 6 digits):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(){
    int pin;

    std::cin>>pin;

    if (pin >= 100000 && pin <= 999999) {
        std::cout << pin << "\n";
        std::string pin_string = std::to_string(pin);
        for (size_t i=0; i<6; ++i){
            std::cout << pin_string[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Invalid input!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Heres one way to do it.

1. Read CIN as std::string
2. Regex recv string for digit only
3. Confirm recv string len is == 6
4. Do w/e you want with it from there

Another way could be getChar()